# htaccess How to RewriteRule with special characters?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website for which I would like to redirect the following requests :

```
www.example.com/wwv_flow.js_messages?p_app_id=103&p_lang=fr&p_version=19.1.0.00.15-51560988
```

To :

```
www.example.com/apex/app/wwv_flow.js_messages?p_app_id=103&p_lang=fr&p_version=19.1.0.00.15-51560988
```

Basically, the rule is whenever the requests starts with **wwv**, then add **apex/app/** right before and keep everything the same.

In my `.htaccess` file I tried :

```
RewriteCond %{HOST_NAME} ^wwv([.]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^wwv([.]+)/?$ ./apex/app/$1 [L]
```

But it's not working. First the condition doesn't work, and second the redirection fails due to the special characters in the URL : **?, &, =**

Does anyone know how to solve that please?

Comment: External "redirect" or _internal rewrite_?

Comment: Did you try the rule generator at [http://www.visiospark.com/mod-rewrite-rule-generator/](http://www.visiospark.com/mod-rewrite-rule-generator/)

Comment: That "rule generator" does not generate the correct rule in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HOST_NAME} ^wwv([.]+)/?$
> RewriteRule ^wwv([.]+)/?$ ./apex/app/$1 [L]
> ```

This rule block will never match the stated URL for several reasons:

- The regex `[.]` (a dot *inside* a character class) matches a literal dot, not "*any character*". The character class negates the dots special meaning. So, `[.]+` matches 1 or more dots. You should remove the square brackets, ie. `.+` in order to match 1 or more "any character". Although to match any request that simply "starts with `wwv`" (as stated in your question), the entire regex can be simplified to `^wwv(.*)`.
- In the `RewriteCond` directive it looks like you are trying to match the `wwv` part against the *hostname*. In your example URL `wwv` is part of the URL-path, not the *hostname*.
- There is no such variable `HOST_NAME`. Perhaps you meant `HTTP_HOST`? However, that is still incorrect (as mentioned above). (You should have used `REQUEST_URI` - in order to match against the URl-path - but then the regex would still have been incorrect. However, this condition is superfluous anyway.)

The `RewriteCond` (condition) directive is not required here. (Repeating the same comparison in the `RewriteCond` that you are performing in the `RewriteRule` directive is superfluous and just results in more "work".)

The `./` prefix on the `RewriteRule` *substitution* is not required here and should be removed.

Note that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only. This notably excludes the query string. (If you specifically needed to match against the query string then you would need a `RewriteCond` directive that matched against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable. But this is not required here.)

> First the condition doesn't work, and second the redirection fails due to the special characters in the URL : `?`, `&`, `=`

These aren't really "special characters" and they should not cause a problem here. It fails because it simply doesn't do anything (as noted above) - it doesn't match the requested URL.

The *query string* is passed through to the *substitution* by default, so there is nothing you need to do regarding the "special characters".

### Solution

> whenever the requests starts with `wwv`, then add `apex/app/` right before and keep everything the same.

To perform the necessary "redirect" you would need something like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^wwv(.*) /apex/app/$1 [R=302,L]
```

The `(.*)` capturing subpattern matches the remainder of the URL-path, ie. `_flow.js_messages` in your example. And this is then referenced in the *substitution* with the `$1` backreference.

As noted above, the query string (ie. `p_app_id=103&p_lang=fr&p_version=19.1.0.00.15-51560988`) is passed through to the *substitution* by default. There is nothing extra you need to do here.

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect.

If you require an *internal rewrite* (as suggested by your code snippet) then remove the `R` flag. And optionally remove the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *substitution* (but this can depend on the value of `RewriteBase` - if any).

```
RewriteRule ^wwv(.*) apex/app/$1 [L]
```

Note that the order of these directives in `.htaccess` is important. If you have existing mod_rewrite directives, then this will likely need to go near the top.

You don't actually need mod_rewrite, if this is the only action you are performing. A mod_alias `RedirectMatch` would suffice. However, mod_rewrite would probably be necessary if you have existing mod_rewrite directives.